# Twilio SMS Not Sending Using Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, twilio

The user will click on a button that will invoke the Parse Cloud function `sendText()`

I've tried both Live Twilio and Testing Twilio accSID and authToken

I first initialize my Twilio by:

```
var Twilio = require('twilio');
Twilio.initialize('accountSid', 'authToken'); //put in my corresponding <<
```

then I set the Parse function by:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('sendText', function(request, response) {

    Twilio.sendSMS({
        From: '+1234567890', //From Number
        To: "+0987654321", //To Number
        Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!" //Message <<
    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
        error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
    });
}
```

It would be great to have someone tell me if something here is wrong or if there are other approaches in sending SMS through Twilio via Parse Cloud.

On the SMS Summary on Twilio, it does not even know any SMS being sent out.

Going on...

The button that calls this cloud function is:

```
<button type="button" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl" onclick="saveData()">CONFIRM</button>
```

and the js function that is called `saveData()` is:

```
function saveData() {
booking.save({
    something: something,
}, {
    success: function (booking) {
        window.location.href = 'final.php';
        Parse.Cloud.run('sendText',
            {
                something: something
        });
    },
    error: function (booking, error) {
        alert('Failed to save');
    }
});
}
```

NO ERROR LOG

Comment: Hi, Twilio developer evangelist here. Your function definition looks correct, but what does the code for your button click look like?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona I have put some more description, thanks for commenting

Comment: I've added an answer. You seem to be using the old module.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You seem to be using an old Parse module which is no longer supported by us. The new module however uses a newer version of our Node module.

Some documentation for it can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-modules-twilio)

It also has some sample code to do what you're trying to do.

```
// Require and initialize the Twilio module with your credentials
var client = require('twilio')('ACCOUNT_SID', 'AUTH_TOKEN');

// Send an SMS message
client.sendSms({
    to:'+0987654321', 
    from: '+1234567890', 
    body: 'Hello world!' 
  }, function(err, responseData) { 
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else { 
      console.log(responseData.from); 
      console.log(responseData.body);
    }
  }
);
```

I think you will find your SMS will be sent using this version of the code. Notice how the initialization is different.

Comment: It still seems to not be working, are there any other suggestions you may have or any other information you might need?

Comment: Do you see any errors being logged? This code should show you weeks the error is.

Comment: Have a look at Parse's examples, but I'm pretty sure it's too do with how many times you're calling success and error on your function. You sold only call them once I think.

Comment: Hey Marcos, I've edited the success/error and edited my question above and tested it. Still no luck

Comment: What's the log saying now?

Comment: No errors have been logged in Parse after I changed the code. SMS still hasn't sent.

Comment: Can you see any entries on Twilio's log page about it trying to send an sms from your Twilio number?

Comment: There are no log entries on Twilio either

Comment: Can you try running that code locally using node.js and see if it works for you?

Comment: How do I run the code using `node.js`? I haven't done that before

Comment: Another thing to do would be to send a test message from the API explorer: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/dev-tools/api-explorer/message-create.  This worked for me and caused me to keep looking over my code until I found the issue.